# Refresh Strings after changing Locate

Tags: android, resources, locate

In my main activity I have `TabHost` with 5 `Activities` as tabs, on one of them I change `Locate` to get locate specific strings, this is the method:

```
private void changeLanguage(String language) {
    Locale mLocale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = mLocale;

    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

}
```

The strings don't change until `setContentView()` is  invoked. (changing device orientation in order to invoke `onCreate()`).

How can I invoke `setContentView()` for another activity or which `method` is invoked after returning to acitivity's screen.